# Find the volume of the solid

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the speciﬁed axis. $x+y = 3$ and $x = 4−(y−1)^2$; about the x-axis.
I get this V = π∫ ((4 - (y-1)^2 )^2 - (3-y)^2 ) dy from 0 to 3 =108pi/5 but webwork says it wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to solve it!

Comment: What have you try so far? Have you seen how to solve this type of problem before ?

Comment: Have you studied the cylindrical shell method? This graph may help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jxlgzvlbxo